# How to reference variable without using global?

Tags: python, global-variables, box2d

I have this function which uses global variables, I also use these very variables in other parts of the code and also this function is crucial for correct functionality of the code as a whole.

However, I found out that it is recommended not to use globals, is there a way I could rewrite the function without using globals? Thank you very much

```
def reset():
    global buildings, my_Car, walkers
        _destroy()

    if len(box2world.bodies) == 0:
        my_Car.destroy_flag = False

        buildings = []
        walkers = []

        create_buildings(bigger_map=False)
        create_pedestrians()
        cars_random_building = random.choice(buildings) #choose a building from the list to generate a car next to the building
        my_Tesla = Car(box2world, position=(cars_random_building.position[0] + 1.55 * cars_random_building.shape[0], cars_random_building.position[1]))
```

The lists buildings and walkers are list of instances of classes Building and Pedestrian respectively.

When I tried not to import the globals I either got an error that variable was referenced before assignment or my Box2D world collapsed during reset because the lists of buildings and walkers were not correctly emptied and so they began to grow to the point that the program collapsed.

Thank you very much

Comment: why don't you use the `return` statement? you could also create a `class`

Comment: actually I am not an experienced programmer so I am not sure how to implement return statement correctly

Comment: And what concerns classes, I admit that I do not really know how this create into a class... Yes I do have another function which could go to the class as a method (class that destroys the car, buildings and walkers) but I do not know how would I implement -or maybe instantiated is better word- the class

Comment: ok, i understand. at this point i think you should simply read a few tutorials on python functions. it is recommended to post a new question only if you did your due diligence and haven't found answers elsewhere. there is a considerable amount of information online about how to use python functions

Comment: Ok, I tried that before asking a question, I know I can for example return multiple parameters but I would say that my basic problem is that I need to modify the global list within the function (or empty the list to be precise) is there a way I could achieve this without using global statement? I couldn't find it anywhere thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could transform all your globals into function parameters and use the return statements for your new Tesla, e. g. :

```
def reset(box2world, buildings, walkers, myCar):
    if not box2world.bodies:
        my_Car.destroy_flag = False
        buildings.clear() 
        walkers.clear() 

        create_buildings(buildings, bigger_map=False)
        create_pedestrians(walkers)
        cars_random_building = random.choice(buildings)
        my_Tesla = Car(box2world, position=(cars_random_building.position[0] + 1.55 * cars_random_building.shape[0], cars_random_building.position[1]))
    return my_Tesla
```

Note that the functions called inside `reset` needs modifications as well.

Comment: Hi, thank you this answer seems to be helpful, I modified the function as you sai, I also tried to modify the functions within the reset function, but when I tried to run the code, I got an error message that my_Tesla was referenced before assignment and when I changed it to myCar and return myCar, the program collapsed. I got similar collapse in the past and if I remember correctly it was caused by continuous expansion of the lists buildings and cars, do you know how would I fix this? I tried to create a chat room with you but I was not succesful